# Current Carrizo APU status

Tags: amd-graphics

As the title says, what is the current status of amd Carrizo APU? I have tried 16.04 with every possible generic kernel and it boots to a blank screen (main issue with this APU). Went back to 15.10 and it works fine with fgrlx. Should I try 14.04.1 and install fgrlx? Last time I saw fgrlx was purged from the trusty repos. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
I used Ubuntu 14.04.1 for a while with the fglrx drivers, and decided to give it the latest kernel a try (4.10 RC5 atm) and it worked flawlessly (obviously I purged/removed fglrx previously). 
So I went ahead and installed 16.04.1 again and installed the 4.10 RC5 kernel and it has been working for a day without blank screens. The only issue is the BCM43142 (WiFi driver) that fails to compile, but I got that covered with a USB WLAN adapter.